# Can I recover history for a SVN repo from a local git-svn repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Our development team is currently using SVN to manage our web application development. The developer managing the SVN server is trying to migrate it from an older Win XP server to another server, but trying to output a dump of the repository fails (corruption or something). Why it is failing is a separate question altogether.

The dev managing the SVN repo suggested exporting the current HEAD of the old repo to use as the base of the new SVN repo, but we will lose all our SVN history. I use git-svn locally which means I have 1.5 years of commit information stored locally. **Is there a way to get these commits out of git-svn and put them in a new SVN repo?**

Comment: Push the commits into a new Git repository instead. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new, empty SVN repo, can you push all the commits from git-svn directly into the repo? (haven't used git or git-svn, but this is what I'd do with one of my hg repos if I needed to get it into an svn repo)

Edit:
I managed to get this to work with manual rebasing via mercurial. The only thing that seems special is the manual rebase instead of the automatic svn rebase. You might try that in git-svn before pulling mercurial into the mix.

1. Create new SVN Repo: `svnadmin create targetSVN`
2. Do initial commit on new SVN repo:

   > `svn co file://targetSVN svnCopy` 
   >    `cd svnCopy`
   >    `touch test`
   >    `svn add test; svn commit -m "Initial Import"`
3. Check the repo out via `hg`: `hg clone file://targetSVN hgCopy; cd hgCopy`
4. Pull in changes from git (via `hg-git`): `hg pull git://yourrepo.git`
5. Manual rebase: `hg rebase -s tip -d 0` (`0` should be the inital SVN commit, and `tip` should be the head of the stuff you pulled from git. Make sure the git changesets are linear (have no merges!). Substitute `tip` for the actual changeset number of the git head (found via `hg heads`) if necessary). Accept all remote changes when it asks about conflicts.
6. `hg push` until all changes are in the svn repo. It pushes 1 changeset at a time.

Comment: git-svn doesn't seem to handle multiple remote svn repos that well; it doesn't want to dcommit my changes to my second svn-remote repo. I don't know if it is properly rebasing all the commits onto the new repo's base commit...

Comment: What happens if you create a new repo, check it out with git-svn, pull in changes from the first git-svn repo, rebase, and then push?

Comment: After rebasing the master branch from the first git-svn repo onto the second git-svn repo's mater branch, `git svn dcommit` fails with "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history. Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 522." `git svn info` also stopped working with the same error.

Comment: Try doing an initial commit in the svn repo and pulling that first. Just `touch` a file, commit it, and delete it after you get the data imported.

Comment: No luck, I was still unable to dcommit the rebased commits from the original git-svn.

Comment: I managed to get it to work via hgsubversion, but that would be a crazy workflow. I'll edit it in my answer in case you wish to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help with a solution. I had a problem with step #5, but that's because I also had a directory called test, so I redid it with a `touch svn-file` instead. However, step #6 fails for me, with "abort: Sorry, can't find svn parent of a merge revision."

Comment: That sounds like you have merges in the history somewhere (you can't push merges into SVN from hgsubversion or git-svn). If you view the history in a tool such as tortoisehg, does it show branching and merging in the repo history?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds familiar. I suppose it's a pretty difficult task, and unfortunately we've just bit the bullet and discarded the history. I opted to share my git repo with any of my coworkers who needed the old history.